# what does the '[0]' mean with $('#div')[0]?

Tags: jquery

What does the [0] mean?  Also is there a reference/manual that i can use to prevent asking simple questions like this..

```
    var height = $('.string-parent-container')[0].scrollHeight;
$('.string-parent-container').scrollTop(height);
```

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page - Contains tutorials and API reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the first element that matches `$('.string-parent-container')`

`$('.string-parent-container')` returns a collection of elements with the class `string-parent-container`. And `[0]` is the first element that has this class.

Answer (score 1):

A different way that returns a jquery object (as opposed to an HTMLElement) would be:

`$('.string-parent-container:eq(0)')` // returns the first object with that class

This allows you to do something like

`$('.string-parent-container:eq(0)').show()`

`$('.string-parent-container:eq(0)').addClass('newclass')`

etc